# SpingBoot @Value without properties file

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible to use the `@Value` annonation with programmatically provided properties? I found out that you can use `@ConfigruationProperites` but you need to provide at least the keys in the properties file. I want to provide values that are known at runtime only programmatically.

I tried this:

```java
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(HostNameConfigurationProperties.class)
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "my")
@Data
public class HostNameConfigurationProperties {
    private String hostname = "lolo";
}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class HostnameconfigApplication implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Value("${my.hostname}")
    private String hostname;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(String.format("hostname: %s", this.hostname));
    }
}
```

But the error is this without corresponding entry in the properties file:

```
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'my.hostname' in value "${my.hostname}"
```

When I add the entry, then it works and I can overwrite it in the code as shown. But it's the point of the question to have no properties file to do this.

Comment: You don't need the keys in the property file. You can specify them as environment, systen or startup properties as well.

Comment: I would like to provide them via POJO instead of property file, env, systemvar or parameter.

Comment: And how do you see that? You recompile for every update in a propery? If it already is in a pojo why even bother with the value annotation?

Comment: It's a value known at runtime (InetAddress::getHostName). Is `@Value` for static values only? I would like to use the `@Value`-Expression instead injecting the pojo and calling getters because I prefer the readability and would like to use the same syntax for proeprties and that pojo values.

Comment: How is an obscured expression better then a direct call to what you need? Also `@Value` is for non-statics (properties can change in the file or throught parameters). You are trying to assign a static value to a parameter, which beats the point of the parameter in the first pace.

Comment: It's really close to a configured port and other properties. It would be nice if I could access them in the same way as other properties.

Comment: Use an `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated class. Use `netAddress::getHostName` as the default value and simply don't specify it in the properties. Although now you do have the possibility to override it.

Comment: I already tried this but without success. I will update my question to show the approach.

Comment: Ofcourse that won't work. You have't specified the value, and using `@Value` won't work. You will have to use the configuration properties and the getter to get the value. If you really want to shoehorn this into something else either use an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` or `ApplicationConfigurer` to pre-proces stuff and add things to propertysources. However I would strongly suggest just to use the configuration properties and inject the properties class when needed.